# Between clause is returning 0 records

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 records in the database matching the criteria but when I run query with between clause it is getting 0 records.

```
$current_date  = date('m-d-Y', strtotime('monday this week'));
$upcoming_date = date('m-d-Y', strtotime('monday next week'));
$sql   = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM result WHERE test_date BETWEEN $current_date AND $upcoming_date AND login = '".$_SESSION['uid'] ."'");
$total_check = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
```

Here is my database

```
result_id`, `login`, `test_id`, `test_date`, 
(1,           '2',      6,      '08-03-2016', 
(2,           '2',      5,      '08-03-2016', 
(3,           '2',      3,      '08-03-2016',
```

Please let me know where and what I am doing wrong as I am getting 0 results and $_SESSION['uid'] is 2

Comment: I think you are missing quotes in dates!! Better use prepare statement!!

Comment: copy paste generated query in the mysql console and see what it gives you.

Comment: check for Errors after executing SQL-statemens. (Hint: mysqli_error() )

Comment: 2 questions. 1) Are your dates stored as strings or datetime in the database. 2) have you considered that your database date format is mm-dd-yyyy not m-d-y?

Comment: I don't think BETWEEN is gonna work with dates in m-d-Y format

Comment: 'monday this week' is not a date

Comment: `BETWEEN` doesn't work reliably for date columns unless they have the `DATE` data type. (It doesn't work reliably for `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` datatypes at all, because of an off-by-one issue at the end of the range.).  The text format of `DATE` data types is `2016-12-31, not `12-31-2016`.

Comment: @Takarii I am using dates as inserted by php function would be in string yes

Comment: @Jens I need dates to be from Monday to Sunday so for that I used this function in order to get the date of Monday for this week and Sunday For this week

Comment: @MarkAlan its easy to do this, but dont forget that when using strings in a query to always suround them with single quotes

Comment: @Takarii Thanks alot it helped me and I will be careful in future thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing your dates incorrectly if you want to use them in range searches like `BETWEEN`.   You must store them in `DATE` columns. Storing them in VARCHAR() columns is a bad idea.

You could use something like this, using [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to work around your misdesigned table.

```
 $current_date  = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('monday this week'));
 $upcoming_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('monday next week'));
 $sql = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM result WHERE STR_TO_DATE(test_date,'%d-%m-%Y') BETWEEN '$current_date' AND '$upcoming_date' AND login = '".$_SESSION['uid'] ."'");
```

To ask MySQL to compare the strings `01-01-2016` and `12-31-2015`, and determine that the latter comes before the former is unreasonable. String comparison is lexical. However, `2015-12-31` obviously comes before `2016-01-01`.

This is a little tricky to get right, because the text string `08-08-2016` does come before `08-15-2016`, by accident. But at the end of year, things collapse.

Comment: Thank you for providing a knowledgeable answer

Answer (score 3):

You should use `'` for $current_date AND $upcoming_date

`"SELECT * FROM result WHERE test_date BETWEEN '$current_date' AND '$upcoming_date' AND login = '".$_SESSION['uid'] ."'"`

Use prepare statement like below to avoid [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

```
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $name);

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // do something with $row
}
```

Comment: Exactly, otherwise the query becomes `BETWEEN 2016-01-01 AND 2016-01-10` for instance and MySQL won't treat them at strings - it will probably treat them as integers to subtract.

Comment: @Tamil I am so silly why i forgot single quote your idea worked for me and also I changed it to prepared statment thank man

Comment: This works until you have a week that spans the end of a month. Then it breaks.